# How to get rid of attribute serialization error?

Tags: java, weblogic12c

We are using Web logic 12.1.3 and Java 1.8.0_45 in a BPM tool. While working on one feature, we are getting the following error in our Application server log.

```
could not deserialize the request scoped attribute with name
```

But, no discrepancy was felt while using application. We need our logs to be clear without any error. Could any one help us with idea?

Thanks in advance.